# Asymptotic expansions with compactly supported terms and smoothing operators

Tags: functional-analysis, asymptotics, pseudo-differential-operators, microlocal-analysis, semiclassical-analysis

Suppose that we have a pseudodifferental operator $A\in \Psi^m(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with symbol $a\in S^m(\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n)$, and $a$ has an asymptotic expansion $a\sim \sum\limits_{j=0}^\infty a_j.$ Suppose further that each $a_j$ is compactly-supported, with the supports non-increasing in $j$. Is $a\in S^{-\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n)$? I know that compactly-supported symbols are smoothing (but the expansion need not preserve the support structure) and so are symbols where each term in the expansion is *zero*. I'm not sure if assuming that the supports form a non-increasing chain helps. Here's an attempt which does not use the precise support structure and feels wrong:

Fix $k\in\mathbb{R}.$ Then, we can write $a=\sum\limits_{j=0}^{k-1}a_j+r_k,$ with $r_k\in S^k(\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n).$ Next,$$|\partial_\xi^\alpha\partial_x^\beta a(x,\xi)|\leq \sum\limits_{j=0}^{k-1} |\partial_\xi^\alpha\partial_x^\beta a_j(x,\xi)|+|\partial_\xi^\alpha\partial_x^\beta r_k(x,\xi)|\leq C_{\alpha,\beta,k}\langle\xi\rangle^{k-|\alpha|},$$ using that $r_k\in S^k(\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n)$ and that each $a_j$ is compactly-supported. There is an issue in this line of logic, though (I believe). The constant depends on $k$ since it depends on where I truncate the asymptotic expansion.

Is this argument flawed? If so, is the claim true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one slight error that may be confusing you, namely that $r_k\in S^{m-k}$ not $S^k$, so the $r_k$ are getting better, not worse.

In particular, you actually don't really need to do any work, it follows just from the fact that $S^l$ closed under summation.

More specifically, to show that $a\in S^{-\infty}$, it suffices to show that $a\in S^{m-N}$ for all $N\in \mathbb{N}$. Then we have by the definition of asymptotic summation that
$$a-\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}a_i=r_N\in S^{m-N}.$$
On the other hand $a_i \in S^{-\infty}\subseteq S^{m-N}$ by assumption, so that $\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}a_i\in S^{m-N}$ are well. Thus $a\in S^{m-N}$ which completes the proof.

In particular, you actually don't need to assume anything about the joint support of $a_i$. On the otherhand, if you assume that $a=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_i$ literally, instead of asymptotically, you need your support condition. This follows from the fact that any member of $S^m$ with compact support is in $S^{-\infty}$.

Comment: Indeed, I was just above to edit the first mistake!

Comment: Ah, that's quite obvious actually. Do you know, by chance, that if one has the given support properties, can we glean anything about the support of the full symbol?

Comment: @user900940 You can always add a symbol in $S^{-\infty}$ without affecting the asymptotic expansion, which can be chosen to have arbitrary support, so sadly I don't think you can get any information on the support of $a$.

Comment: Of course, thank you!